# Showing who is online/offline using Javascript, PHP, PDO, CSS, html

Tags: javascript, php, css, pdo

I'm stuck on how to start on this. I think either JavaScript, or PHP is required, or both to perform this functionality I need.

I've got a list of member profiles on a page to which next to each member name, I have currently a placeholder using only CSS and html that SHOULD display whether or not a member who is logged in is online (green dot) or if a member is logged out, it shows that they are offline (grey dot).

I do not have any JavaScript or PHP written up at all as I don't know where to start..., but it would be needed just for this small section and know it's something I'd need to make it work.  All I can do is provide what html I have and CSS I have. I'd like it to perform a scan of who is logged in/out at least every 15-30 seconds only refreshing this small section (online - green dot or offline - grey dot) rather than the entire page (which I'm sure JavaScript is best for this) and of course to see whether or not a member is in fact online/offline by running a query on the session[ID] (which I'm sure PHP/PDO is best practice).  Could anyone help steer me in the right direction from just the little CSS and HTML I have?

HTML:

```
<div id="profile">
    <img src="images/ImagePlacedHere.jpg" width="80" height="80" style="margin: 4px 5px; float: left;" />
    <h2>Jason <online title="Online" /></h2>
</div>

<div id="profile">
    <img src="images/ImagePlacedHere.jpg" width="80" height="80" style="margin: 4px 5px; float: left;" />
    <h2>Nick <offline title="Offline" /></h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#profile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 8px;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 28px 24px -24px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  float: left;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -3px;
}
#profile:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0, inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0, inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0, inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
}
#profile h2 {
  width: 195px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 8px 0 1px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  float: left;
  color: #B45F04;
  font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=315,strength=2,color=000000);
}
#profile h2 online {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #009D0D;
  border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 1px -1px #000, inset 0 -1px 4px 1px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 1px -1px #000, inset 0 -1px 4px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 1px -1px #000, inset 0 -1px 4px 1px #000;
  float: right;
}
#profile h2 offline {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 1px -1px #000, inset 0 -1px 4px 1px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 1px -1px #000, inset 0 -1px 4px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 1px -1px #000, inset 0 -1px 4px 1px #000;
  float: right;
}
```

Here is a demo of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/tZpk6/

If more information is needed, I might be able to provide some more (possibly)...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use AJAX (I suggest using jQuery for this, it hides a lot of boiler plate code) to query the server once every `X` seconds.

You will have a script on your server that queries your database, asking if a user is online. You are going to need to track when a user was last seen, and decide how long is long enough between page impressions by your given user to decide when they are offline (IE 5 mins).

From that, you can just return a true/false response from your PHP script and update your green/gray dot accordingly.

If you want to get even more advanced, you can look into something like [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) which with the help of [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) you can keep track of users in real time.

Comment: No. NodeJS lets you create full stack applications in Javascript. Meaning, you write your server parts in Javascript, similar to how you already do so in PHP. You can use NodeJS in tandem with your PHP scripts.

Comment: Is there a simpler solution?  I am a little familiar with `javascript` and `php`, but when it comes to `AJAX` and what you recommended `NodeJS` and `Socket.IO` I literally have no experience with at all.  Is what I'm asking fall under this criteria? and well, as I'm sure it is, is there a major learning curve?

Comment: I gave two possible solutions in my answer. You can either use a little Javascript and PHP, or you can try using NodeJS if you want to try something new. Given what you have asked, those are the two things I would suggest you try. If you want to learn something new, I suggest NodeJS. If you need this done sooner rather than later, I would suggest simple AJAX calls to PHP scripts.

Comment: NodeJS would be something I'd like to venture into down the road, but for this project - I'd have to get it running sooner than later.  If I go with the alternate `AJAX` and `PHP` rather than `Javascript` and `PHP` how would I even start that?  I don't have any experience in `AJAX` and only little in `PHP`...would the AJAX perform the scan and refresh the small section (online/offline) similar to how javascript would?  And if so, where do I begin?

Comment: AJAX you would do in Javascript. It is just a way to call a script on the server to retrieve some information. Simple Google-ing will help you. There are a great number of questions related to AJAX here on SO. The PHP script will only really need to query to database and ask if a certain user was seen recently.

Answer (score 0):

It's got nothing to do with client side Javascript. It's got nothing to do with HTML. If these aren't obvious then you've got a long journey ahead of you. You did ask the question nealry 9 years ago - maybe the answer will make more sense now (not sure why stack overflow has pushed this up to the front page).

You need to implement this in the session management of your application back end. And it also means replacing most of the session management code provided by whatever platform you decide to build this on. Scanning the currently open sessions to see which are active is a fairly obvious solution - but if your session data is large that could get very slow very quickly. You could alleviate the impact the impact by dissociating the checks from user HTTP access, but personally I'd go with putting a decorator on top of the session handler and maintaining an active user list as a separate data store in a database. You need to check the time the data was created/last updated - most web based session managers use a garbage collection model based on inactivity to remove old sessions.